# Sorting array of directory paths by actual directory structure

Tags: c#

I have an array of directories (a search which includes subdirectories). I'd like to sort the results, like so:

```
Test
---A
----A.A
---B
```

So the collection lists the directory, and then all of the directories within it, and so forth, for every directory.

How could I sort an array like this?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't sorting the list alphabetically solve this?

Comment: @Jon, I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Jon's solution would work if the array contains the full path of the directories (or objects of some type that give access to the full path).  If the array doesn't contain that information, then it would be considerably harder to solve the problem!

Comment: @phoog See my answer to your previous comment. Why not try to avoid the need for sorting? Abe should know if it's possible in his case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If sorting this alphabetically will do this for you (which I think it should)...

With

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\");
```

You should be able to use

```
string[] sorted = dirs.OrderBy(d => d).ToArray();
```

or

```
Array.Sort(dirs);
```

Comment: This doesn't always work. For example sorting `"Program Files", "Program Files (x86)", "Program Files\test", "Program Files (x86)\test"` will result in `"Program Files", "Program Files (x86)", "Program Files (x86)\test", "Program Files\test"`

Answer (score 0):

If your search is recursive you don't need sorting.

Comment: The OP is asking about sorting a flat set of directories, not a recursive data structure.  It's possible that the array was created with a recursive function, but is still not in the desired order.  For example, the procedure might first add all of a directory's children, and then call itself on each of the directory's children.

Comment: @phoog I understand completely, but if the search is done by the same application, why not just optimize the whole thing in such fashion that no subsequent sorting is needed? After all, sorting is an important resource consumer, so try to avoid as much as possible. If not, then sort it smart ;)

Comment: @Adi good point.  I overlooked the (very highly probable) possibility that the OP was assembling the array himself in the first place. :-S

Comment: But (I just checked this out) if he's using the framework method System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories with SearchOption.AllDirectories, the result would be as I described. It's much less coding to call that method and then sort the result.

Comment: @phoog Nice finding... Don't know the very specific of the problem here... But i guess we helped enough the OP as he is not active

Comment: Or he went out for some Friday night fun right after he posted, and will tell us on Monday how we misunderstood his question.